# Create a folder in downloads and Download multiple images from external server on single click in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image

I want to **download multiple images on single click**.
I have **external links** of the images.

https://focalassetsstagingcdn.azureedge.net/orders2021/971014/photosraw/0ba59d1b-83be-42af-a9dd-f1c10e69f540.jpg

https://focalassetsstagingcdn.azureedge.net/orders2021/971014/photosraw/0dcfb56e-5a25-4fb0-bb9c-dd36ddab561c.jpg

Any method which will **create a folder in my PC Downloads and save all images in it**.
I have HostGator Linux dedicate server hosting with cPanel

My app is based on **PHP 7/JS/jQuery/Bootstrap**.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, it will be helpful if providing a snippet of your code instead of the target images. Check out [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) { //turn directory not found warning into exception
    if (0 === error_reporting()) {
        return false;
    }       
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
});
$imagesarray = array("https://focalassetsstagingcdn.azureedge.net/orders2021/971014/photosraw/0ba59d1b-83be-42af-a9dd-f1c10e69f540.jpg", "https://focalassetsstagingcdn.azureedge.net/orders2021/971014/photosraw/0dcfb56e-5a25-4fb0-bb9c-dd36ddab561c.jpg"); //all the images url that you have in an array
$destination = "downloaded_images/"; //your folder name
$imagecount = sizeof($imagesarray);
for($i=0 ; $i < $imagecount; $i++) {
    try{ //The folder may not exist
        file_put_contents($destination.$i.".jpg", file_get_contents($imagesarray[$i]));
    }
    catch(Exception $e){ //if so create a folder and startover.
        mkdir($destination);
        $i--;
    }
} ?>
```

Note: This will leave-out some other exceptions like permission denied, which needs to be handled differently.